# How to switch from a subrepo development to a new repo keeping all the history?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, subtree

Here is a realistic scenario with a bit simplified main actors:

- There is a repo: `device` [here](https://github.com/apaj/device)
- There is a repo: `ourdevice` [here](https://bitbucket.org/apaj/ourdevice)

`device` is something developed by a third person.

`ourdevice` is my repo, which I created to work on further development of the `device`. I wanted to be able to do my own changes, but also be able to occasionally merge in the changes introduced by that third person. So I chose to go with **subtree** back then. [This article](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec) was used as a reference heavily.

Now, I've come to a point where I am quite happy with my development of `ourdevice` and I'd like to embed `ourdevice` in a system developed for embedding the `device`. Unfortunately, there is that additional level of hierarchy: `device` is a subtree of the `ourdevice`, thus the folder structure in `ourdevice` is: `ourdevice/device/-all-the-rest-`.

I'd like to translate `ourdevice` into a new repo, be it BitBucket or GitHub by achieving both:

1. removing that additional level of hierarchy, and
2. keeping all the development history (commits, branches, everything) while working on `device` within `ourdevice`.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you.